# Migration from foundation 5.5.3 to 6.6.1

Tags: zurb-foundation

do you know how any documentation or something like that for migrating it? I've searched on google and on zurb foundation 6 documentation page but I didn't understand very much and it didn't work. Do you know if there's a documentation that works?

Answer (score 0):

We have no official migration guide or path and there are big differences.

Best is you create a new project from scratch.